# MySQL Average Column On Pivot Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that goes something like this

```
loanprocessorusername     borrower     fundingdate
jonsmith                  borrower2    8/10/15
jonsmith                  borrower2    8/10/16
username3                 borrower4    9/9/15
```

And so on and so forth.
Basically I am tasked to create a pivot table to get a count of how many loans were completed by the loanprocessorusername by month in a given year. I am using borrower to get the count when in fact in can be really any field. The PK is loannumber

In any case this is how far I have gotten:

```
SELECT loanprocessorusername, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 8 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2015 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Aug2015, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 9 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2015 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Sep2015, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 10 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2015 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Oct2015, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 11 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2015 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Nov2015, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 12 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2015 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Dec2015, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 1 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2016 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Jan2016, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2016 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Feb2016, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 3 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2016 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Mar2106, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 4 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2016 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Apr2016, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 5 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2016 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS May2016, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 6 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2016 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Jun2016, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 7 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2016 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Jul2016, 
   Count(CASE 
           WHEN Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 8 
                AND Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2016 
         THEN 
           borrower 
           ELSE NULL 
         END)      AS Aug2016, 
   Count(borrower) AS GrandTotal 
FROM   dataset 
WHERE  loan_lienposition = 'first' 
GROUP  BY loanprocessorusername;
```

I want to add a final column for average, however when I try to do avg(borrower) I get all zeros. If I try to do count(borrower)/13 which is the number of months it doesnt give me the desired results.
Ideally the zeros should be null and the average should be calculated based on the number of actual values (non null)
Basically my question is. How do I add an average column do this pivot table

Thanks

Comment: sounds like NULLIF(ColumnName,0) will be useful to you SUM(ValueColumnName) / IFNULL(NULLIF(COUNT(NULLIF(ColumnName,0)),0),1)

Comment: hmm.. Ill try that out. The SUM function you mentioned needs to be applied to a column with a numerical value correct, such as count. Is there way I can sum the existing columns from pivot table?

Comment: Yes sum has to be to a numerical column. You mention you want Average thought which has to be a numerical column.....  Average is the SUM of something divided by the count of occurrences.  I honestly can't tell what you are wanting the average of so I am not positive how to answer more than general guidance.  If you want to post example data and desired result I could more specifically answer your question

Comment: `count(borrower)/13` should work. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: count(borrower)/13 does work however I want the average to be calculated on positive values only. Meaning a 0 value would not contribute to the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT loanprocessorusername, 
       CONCAT(
               Month(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y'),
               Year(Str_to_date(status_fundingdate, '%m/%d/%Y')
             ) AS MY,
       COUNT(1) AS COunt_Of_Loans_per_each_user
  FROM table 
GROUP BY 1,2
;
```

Comment: Yes it gives me the count of loans correctly, however the issue I am having is trying to get the average of all loans for each loanprocessorusername. Hope that make sense

Comment: You need to write another query to calculate average for each loanprocessorusername and join back with the above SQL.